# Why is there a KeyError

Tags: python

The following is a LeetCode question:

> Given an integer array nums which is sorted in ascending order and all
> of its elements are unique and given also an integer k, return the kth
> missing number starting from the leftmost number of the array.

I wrote a solution (not the best one), and am getting a KeyError. This is being run on the Leetcode platform. Here is my solution:

```
class Solution:
    def missingElement(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        missing_dict = {}
        c = 0
        min_nums = nums[0]
        max_nums = nums[len(nums)-1]
        for num in range(min_nums, max_nums):
            num += 1
            if num not in nums:
                c += 1
                missing_dict[c] = num
        return missing_dict[k]
```

Some examples:

```
Input: nums = [4,7,9,10], k = 1
Output: 5
Explanation: The first missing number is 5.

Input: nums = [4,7,9,10], k = 3
Output: 8
Explanation: The missing numbers are [5,6,8,...], hence the third missing number is 8.
```

I get the following error: `KeyError: 3`. I don't understand why I am getting this error? The last executed input was `nums = [1,2,4]` and `k=3` and the expected value was `6`.

**Added.** Since we know the array is sorted in ascending order, I am looping through the array, adding 1 to each element and checking to see if it is in the array. If it is not, then I set the first missing element to that value (`missing_dict[1] = value`). If the next element aka `value+1` is in the array then `k` is still 1. Otherwise we increment `k` by `1` and `missing_dict[2] = value+1` etc..

**Added** I just realized the kth missing number doesn't have to be in [min_nums, max_nums]. That wasn't clear before.

**Added**

```
1 <= nums.length <= 5 * 10^4
1 <= nums[i] <= 10^7
nums is sorted in ascending order, and all the elements are unique.
1 <= k <= 10^8
```

**Partial Solution**

Here is a partial solution using binary search:

```
class Solution:
    def missingElement(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        def count_missing(x: int) -> int:
            return x-min(nums)-1
        def binary_search_recursive(nums, k, start, end):
            if start > end:
                return -1
            mid = (start + end) // 2
            if(count_missing(nums[mid]) > 0):
                if count_missing(nums[mid]) >= k:
                    return nums[start]+k
                else:
                    return nums[mid]+(k-count_missing(nums[mid]))

            if count_missing(nums[mid]) >= k:
                return binary_search_recursive(nums, k, start, mid-1)
            else:
                return binary_search_recursive(nums, k, mid+1, end)
                
        
        return binary_search_recursive(nums, k, 0, len(nums)-1)
```

It fails for `nums = [2,3,5,7]` and `k =1` where the output is
`6` when it should be `4`.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for someone to recreate the error.

Comment: I don't think it should be downvoted, but you should include a few more lines to make this a working example. That helps us run the code and make fixes.

Comment: What does this have to do with *binary-search*?

Comment: "I don't understand why I am getting this error?" This is the wrong way to think about the question. Try to explain to us, step by step, *why it should not* cause an error, and exactly *what should happen instead*.

Comment: Can you link the challenge?

Comment: Hint: where the code says `return missing_dict[k]`, what is that intended to mean?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I guess I was assuming that the user would always enter a valid value of `k`. That is a wrong assumption probably.

Comment: @ScottHunter I think it *can* be solved efficiently with binary search, but yeah, their code doesn't and their question isn't about that.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yes it can be solved with binary search in O(log(n)) time. But I just wanted to get the correct solution first.

Comment: I can't understand how the algorithm is intended to work. Try to explain your approach to the solution, step by step, in English.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I added some more details.

Comment: I just realized the kth missing number doesn't have to be in [min_nums, max_nums]. That wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: You don't need a missing dict.  Just start at the first number, count if it isn't in the list and check if you reached the kth count.  increment the number and repeat.

Comment: It's probably clear from the whole problem specification. Like, what limits are stated for the length of the list and for k?

Comment: @KellyBundy: I added some constraints, but it seems that this doesn't explicitly tell us that the kth missing element doesn't have to be in the set. I apologize for not putting this as this is my first time using LeetCode.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Thanks. This was a "solution" I came up with a 5 minute time limit. I realize there are much better solutions.

Comment: Those constraints look weird. Are you sure they're not powers of 10?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Good point, I corrected it. Is there LaTeX in this forum?

Comment: I don't think so. You could HTML `<sup>`, but `^` is fine.

Comment: As I thought, the limits indicate that the result number can be larger than the largest number in the list. Note how large `k` is allowed to be compared to the (numbers in) the list.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Thanks I should have seen that.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the problem on Leetcode Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause of the key error:**

You are getting the key error because the max limit is set to the maximum element of `nums`. For the given test case `nums = [1, 2, 4], k = 3`, the missing element is `6` but the dictionary does not contain any key of `3`.

From OP comment,

> I just realized the kth missing number doesn't have to be in
> [min_nums, max_nums]. That wasn't clear in the question.

**Solution:**

We can use a dictionary to store the given `nums` list. Then start checking which numbers are not present in the dictionary from the first number on the list.

```
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def missingElement(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        data = {}
        for i in nums:
            data[i] = 1
        i = nums[0]
        while k != 0:
            if i not in data:
                k -= 1
            i += 1
        return i - 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    solution = Solution()
    nums = [4, 7, 9, 10]
    k = 1
    print(solution.missingElement(nums, k))

    nums = [4, 7, 9, 10]
    k = 3
    print(solution.missingElement(nums, k))

    nums = [1, 2, 4]
    k = 3
    print(solution.missingElement(nums, k))
```

Output:

```
5
8
6
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why he's getting a KeyError in his code.

Comment: Is this O(n) time complexity?

Comment: We can identify this as an `O(k+n)` solution assuming the dictionary search is `O(1)`.

Comment: @arsho: Thanks for the answer. Any ideas how to rectify my solution?

Comment: @AnthonyAndiles, we cannot continuously update the question and answer, can we? Otherwise, it will have multiple questions and multiple answers. If this answer solves your initial `key error` problem, maybe you can accept this and ask another question. Thank you.